# tkz-fct: error message when plotting tangent line

Tags: tkz-collection

I tried to plot tangent lines to the graph of a function using tkz-fct. See the example below. However I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: Use of \tkz@DrawTangentLine doesn't match its definition.

--- TeX said ---
\pgfutil@ifnextchar ...1\def \pgfutil@reserved@a {
                                              #2}\def \pgfutil@reserved@...
 l.17       \tkzDrawTangentLine[draw](4)
```

Any idea what's wrong with my code?

The example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usetkzobj{all}


    \begin{document}

       \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1]
          \tikzset{tan style/.style={-}}
          \tkzInit[xmin=0,xmax=10,xstep=1,
          ymin=0,ymax=5,ystep=1]
          \tkzGrid[color=brown,sub,subxstep=50,subystep=200]
          \tkzAxeXY
          \tkzFct[color=red,samples=100,domain = 0:10]{sqrt(1/2.*\x) + sin(1/2.*\x)}
          \tkzDrawTangentLine[draw](4)
       \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you don't need `usetkzobj`. This is for `tkz-euclide`. Now the problem comes from `sqrt``, a possibility is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1]
\tikzset{tan style/.style={-}}
\tkzInit[xmin=0,xmax=10,xstep=1,
        ymin=0,ymax=5,ystep=1]
\tkzGrid[color=brown,sub,subxstep=50,subystep=200]
\tkzAxeXY
\tkzFct[color=red,samples=100,domain = 0:10]{(1./2*\x)**(0.5) + sin(1./2*\x)}
\tkzDrawTangentLine[draw](4)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation : The code is very tricky : first the syntax is the gnuplot's syntax to draw the graph but then to draw some points and the tangent line, I use FP. So I created a macro to translate the gnuplot expression with the syntax of FP. When I wrote `tkz-fct`, I did not know how to use gnuplot to calculate a single value, now I know how to make this ... but with Lua, perhaps it's preferable to wait some time and to write new macros with luatex.
In the case of `sqrt`, I think I need to modify something because this is a bug !